# How can I limit the maximum number of lambda invocations in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function triggered by a FIFO SQS. The queue has 50,000 messages to be processed but I want to process only 200 by hour. How can I do it? This is a question more about the solution architecture rather then code itself.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's much on AWS that can help you directly.  Best I can think of is instead of triggering your Lambda directly from SQS, you could trigger it with an event rule based on a cron expression, but you can only do max resolution of one minute, so you'd have to make the math of invocations per hour times messages per invocation to equal 200.  To me this sounds like an X Y problem

Comment: You can use `reservedConcurrency` for the lambda to limit the maximum concurrent messages processed at a time. But to restrict that to 200 messages/hour will take some trial and error approach, and knowing the processing time for each message.